# SignalR 2 Not working on azurewebsites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket, signalr

I have a simple SignalR based timer on the server which updates my dashboard panel. Everything works fine on VS2012, however when I deploy to azure or IIS7.5 it can't stablish a connection. [Here are the errors from console](http://screencast.com/t/6ljxpyuZiuRY).

This is my hub:

```
public class BroadCastHub : Hub
{

    // Is set via the constructor on each creation 
    //private readonly Broadcaster _broadcaster;
    private readonly TimeSpan BroadcastInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(AppConfig.Instance.Tracing.RefreshRate * 1000);

    public BroadCastHub()  {
        if (AppConfig.Instance.Tracing.EnableServerAutoUpdates)
        {
            // Start the broadcast loop
            var _broadcastLoop = new Timer(
                UpdatePanel,
                null,
                BroadcastInterval,
                BroadcastInterval);
        }
    }

    public void UpdatePanel()
    {
        UpdatePanel(null);
    }

    public void UpdatePanel(object o)
    {

        var appService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IApplicationService>();
        var applications = appService.GetSummaryCollection();
        var model = applications.Select(c => new ApplicationState
        {
            id = c.id,
            lastRunTime = c.lastRunTime.GetValueOrDefault(),
            totalTraces = c.totalTraces,
            status = appService.GetStatus(c.lastRunTime, c.lastTraceType, c.traceInterval)
        }.InjectFrom(c)).Cast<ApplicationState>().AsQueryable();

        Clients.All.updatePanel(model);

    }

}
```

This is my JS code (Angular):

```
   function init() {

        var broadCastHub = $.connection.broadCastHub;
        broadCastHub.client.updatePanel = function(apps) {
            console.log('Broadcasting');
        };

        $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function () {
            console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id);
        })
        .fail(function () { console.log('Could not Connect!'); });

        //listenBroadcast();
    }
```

**EDIT**: 
Curiously, I saw a similar article and implemented like this:

```
public class Broadcaster
{
    private readonly IApplicationService _applicationService;
    private readonly static Lazy<Broadcaster> _instance = new Lazy<Broadcaster>(() => new Broadcaster());
    // We're going to broadcast to all clients a maximum of 25 times per second
    private readonly TimeSpan BroadcastInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(AppConfig.Instance.Tracing.RefreshRate * 1000);
    private readonly IHubContext _hubContext;
    private Timer _broadcastLoop;

    public Broadcaster()
    {
        _applicationService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IApplicationService>();
        // Save our hub context so we can easily use it 
        // to send to its connected clients
        _hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<BroadCastHub>();

        if (AppConfig.Instance.Tracing.EnableServerAutoUpdates) { 
            // Start the broadcast loop
            _broadcastLoop = new Timer(
                UpdatePanel,
                null,
                BroadcastInterval,
                BroadcastInterval);
        }

    }

    public void UpdatePanel(object state)
    {
        var applications = _applicationService.GetSummaryCollection();
        var model = applications.Select(c => new ApplicationState
        {
            id = c.id,
            lastRunTime = c.lastRunTime.GetValueOrDefault(),
            totalTraces = c.totalTraces,
            status = _applicationService.GetStatus(c.lastRunTime, c.lastTraceType, c.traceInterval)
        }.InjectFrom(c)).Cast<ApplicationState>().AsQueryable();

        _hubContext.Clients.All.updatePanel(model);

    }

    public static Broadcaster Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

My hub:

```
public class BroadCastHub : Hub
{

    // Is set via the constructor on each creation 
    private readonly Broadcaster _broadcaster; 

    public BroadCastHub() 
        : this(Broadcaster.Instance) 
    { 
    }

    public BroadCastHub(Broadcaster broadcaster) 
    { 
        _broadcaster = broadcaster; 
    } 

    public void UpdatePanel() 
    { 
        _broadcaster.UpdatePanel(null); 
    }
```

}

Thanks for the article, I'll take a deeper look.

Comment: Have you turned on Websockets in your azure dashboard?

Comment: Yes, I did : http://screencast.com/t/ifvVU8QV

Comment: There is a connection limit for websocket on azure. Check on your network tab if signalr succeds in establishing at least one connection.If this is a free account, you can only have 5 concurrent connections on websockets I think.

Comment: Well, I'm having the same issue in a IIS 7.5 web server, so I don't think it would be this, anyway I'll give it a look. Thanks !!

Comment: Never create timers in the hub, they are created everytime something is called on the hub. Read the server broadcast tutorial to get an idea of how to achieve what you're doing http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr-20